# Company exceeding Index weight percentage cap

Tags: investing, etf

I was looking at the Index [MSCI World SRI Select Reduced Fossil Fuels](https://www.msci.com/documents/10199/75bae2dd-7f6a-8f05-99dd-d13d145e2e75) where it says:

> The Index is float-adjusted market capitalization weighted and a 5% capping with
> 10% buffer is applied on issuer weights in the Index.

But Tesla is listed as the top constituent with an Index weight of 6.68%.
How can this happen?

Answer (score 5):

The "5% capping" is not a legal limit. It's a statement of policy or guideline. There is no penalty for a single by-the-letter infringement - in fact that's why it says "with a 10% buffer."

To answer "how can this happen", the way it usually happens is that the fund manager likes Tesla and invests 5% of the fund in it. Tesla then rises in price faster than the other holdings, meaning it now represents more than 5% of the fund. However the manager doesn't want to sell off Tesla immediately, so there is a period when Tesla makes up 6.68% of the fund.

If the fund keeps more than 5% Tesla for a long period they risk being punished for misrepresentation (i.e. the fund told investors that they wouldn't hold more than 5% of a stock, but they aren't actually doing that). But there is definitely leeway while the fund reduces its Tesla holding in an orderly and profitable fashion.